# CMU sphinx Acoustic model, lexicon and dictionary path error using windows command prompt

Tags: command-prompt, pocketsphinx

I am  trying to create a speech-to-text program using CMU Sphinx--pocketsphinx with sphinxbase using windows 7 command prompt. i have been receiving the error that option `-hmm -lm -dict` cannot be located. 
such as this error

![1]:https://i.stack.imgur.com/II8Th.png "error of command prompt"
or more precisely:

```
D:\CMUsphinx>cd pocketsphinx

D:\CMUsphinx\pocketsphinx>bin\Release\Win32\pocketsphinx_continuous.exe -inmic y
es
Current configuration:
[NAME]                  [DEFLT]         [VALUE]
-agc                    none            none
-agcthresh              2.0             2.000000e+000
-allphone
-allphone_ci            no              no
-alpha                  0.97            9.700000e-001
-ascale                 20.0            2.000000e+001
-aw                     1               1
-backtrace              no              no
-beam                   1e-48           1.000000e-048
-bestpath               yes             yes
-bestpathlw             9.5             9.500000e+000
-ceplen                 13              13
-cmn                    current         current
-cmninit                8.0             8.0
-compallsen             no              no
-debug                                  0
-dict
-dictcase               no              no
-dither                 no              no
-doublebw               no              no
-ds                     1               1
-fdict
-feat                   1s_c_d_dd       1s_c_d_dd
-featparams
-fillprob               1e-8            1.000000e-008
-frate                  100             100
-fsg
-fsgusealtpron          yes             yes
-fsgusefiller           yes             yes
-fwdflat                yes             yes
-fwdflatbeam            1e-64           1.000000e-064
-fwdflatefwid           4               4
-fwdflatlw              8.5             8.500000e+000
-fwdflatsfwin           25              25
-fwdflatwbeam           7e-29           7.000000e-029
-fwdtree                yes             yes
-hmm
-input_endian           little          little
-jsgf
-keyphrase
-kws
-kws_delay              10              10
-kws_plp                1e-1            1.000000e-001
-kws_threshold          1               1.000000e+000
-latsize                5000            5000
-lda
-ldadim                 0               0
-lifter                 0               0
-lm
-lmctl
-lmname
-logbase                1.0001          1.000100e+000
-logfn
-logspec                no              no
-lowerf                 133.33334       1.333333e+002
-lpbeam                 1e-40           1.000000e-040
-lponlybeam             7e-29           7.000000e-029
-lw                     6.5             6.500000e+000
-maxhmmpf               30000           30000
-maxwpf                 -1              -1
-mdef
-mean
-mfclogdir
-min_endfr              0               0
-mixw
-mixwfloor              0.0000001       1.000000e-007
-mllr
-mmap                   yes             yes
-ncep                   13              13
-nfft                   512             512
-nfilt                  40              40
-nwpen                  1.0             1.000000e+000
-pbeam                  1e-48           1.000000e-048
-pip                    1.0             1.000000e+000
-pl_beam                1e-10           1.000000e-010
-pl_pbeam               1e-10           1.000000e-010
-pl_pip                 1.0             1.000000e+000
-pl_weight              3.0             3.000000e+000
-pl_window              5               5
-rawlogdir
-remove_dc              no              no
-remove_noise           yes             yes
-remove_silence         yes             yes
-round_filters          yes             yes
-samprate               16000           1.600000e+004
-seed                   -1              -1
-sendump
-senlogdir
-senmgau
-silprob                0.005           5.000000e-003
-smoothspec             no              no
-svspec
-tmat
-tmatfloor              0.0001          1.000000e-004
-topn                   4               4
-topn_beam              0               0
-toprule
-transform              legacy          legacy
-unit_area              yes             yes
-upperf                 6855.4976       6.855498e+003
-uw                     1.0             1.000000e+000
-vad_postspeech         50              50
-vad_prespeech          20              20
-vad_startspeech        10              10
-vad_threshold          2.0             2.000000e+000
-var
-varfloor               0.0001          1.000000e-004
-varnorm                no              no
-verbose                no              no
-warp_params
-warp_type              inverse_linear  inverse_linear
-wbeam                  7e-29           7.000000e-029
-wip                    0.65            6.500000e-001
-wlen                   0.025625        2.562500e-002

INFO: feat.c(715): Initializing feature stream to type: '1s_c_d_dd', ceplen=13,
CMN='current', VARNORM='no', AGC='none'
INFO: cmn.c(143): mean[0]= 12.00, mean[1..12]= 0.0
ERROR: "acmod.c", line 80: Acoustic model definition is not specified either wit
h -mdef option or with -hmm

D:\CMUsphinx\pocketsphinx>    -hmm model\en-us\en-us -lm model\en-us\en-us.lm.bi
n
'-hmm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

D:\CMUsphinx\pocketsphinx>    -dict model\en-us\cmudict-en-us.dict
```

i have googled for hours for how to set the path for acoustic model,language model path and the dictionary path as well.

i tried following this tutorial from youtube

![1]:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OjMX75RVjOs

I have tried many ways of moving files in respecting folder.. but still i am getting this error.

Can anyone give a guide on how to set the path for those 3 models?
i am confused.

Comment: The command line is correct `bin\Release\Win32\pocketsphinx_continuous.exe -inmic yes -hmm model\en-us\en-us -lm model\en-us\en-us.lm.bin -dict model\en-us\cmudict-en-us.dict`, you just need to type it in a single line without newlines before `-hmm`. This is an intentional protection from dumb copy-pasters who copy code without understanding.

Comment: ohh i see..
now i get it.. Thank you for pointing out the mistake. yes i admit that i copy pasted the line.
Thank you sir